# front end dynamic Design remove button

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, frontend

this is a project I made it is a library in which when you click the pic you can add the book name and price to a table and have the total price I need to add a removing button or to remove the books I want from both the total and the table

first trial

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        img{
            margin: 3px;
            cursor: pointer;
            box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px 2px violet;
            border: 4px groove darkviolet;
        }
        div{
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
            grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr ;
            background-color: azure;
            padding: 7px;
            border: 4px groove greenyellow;
        }
        .c1{
            border: 10px ridge crimson;
        }
        #d2{
            display: flexbox;
            flex-basis: 4;
            background-color: bisque;
        }
        #b1{
            grid-column: 0/1;
            grid-row: 1/3;
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
            margin: 4px;
        }
        #t1{
            grid-column: 2/4;
            grid-row: 1/3;
            border: 3px solid blue;
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 1.5px 1px skyblue;
            margin:5px;
        }
        table{
            background-color: antiquewhite;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
            border: 4px solid sandybrown;
        }
        tr{
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
        }
        td{
            margin: 10px;
            color: turquoise;
            border: 1.5px solid black;
            padding: 6px;
            
        }
      
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="d1">
    <img src="b1.jpg" alt="book1" width="50%">
    <img src="b2.jpg" alt="book2" width="50%">
    <img src="b3.jpg" alt="book3" width="50%">
    <img src="b4.jpg" alt="book4" width="50%">
    <img src="b5.jpg" alt="book5" width="50%">
    <img src="b6.jpg" alt="book6" width="50%">
    <img src="b7.jpg" alt="book7" width="50%">
    <img src="b8.jpg" alt="book8" width="50%">
    </div>
    <table id="ta">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>SN:-</td>
                <td>Book name</td>
                <td>Price</td>
                
                
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tb">
            
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <input type="button" value="price" id="b1" >  
            <input type="text" aria-label="price" id="t1">
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</body>
<script>
    var allBooks = [
        {name:"b1.jpg",title:"A Hero Born", Price: 20},
        {name:"b2.jpg",title:"Pearless Martial God", Price: 45},
        {name:"b3.jpg",title:"Five Rings Of Cultivation", Price: 14},
        {name:"b4.jpg",title:"Book Eater", Price: 19},
        {name:"b5.jpg",title:"Dual Sword God", Price: 15},
        {name:"b6.jpg",title:"Dragon Heart", Price: 18},
        {name:"b7.jpg",title:"Listening To Rain", Price: 55},
        {name:"b8.jpg",title:"The Hidden Blade", Price: 40}
    ];
    var selectedBooks = [];
    var b = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for(var i = 0 ; i < b.length;i++){
        b[i].addEventListener("click",fun);

    };
    function fun(event){
        if(event.target.getAttribute("class")=="c1"){
        event.target.setAttribute("class","");}
        else{event.target.setAttribute("class","c1")}
        
    };
   ;
    var tP = 0;
    var sb = document.getElementsByClassName("c1");
    document.getElementById("b1").addEventListener("click",fun3);
    function fun3(){
    
    for(var i = 0; i < sb.length;i++){
        var ssb = sb[i].getAttribute("src");
        var n = 0;
        for(var j = 0 ; j < allBooks.length;j++ ){
            n ++;
            if(ssb==allBooks[j].name){
               
                var r = `<tr><td> ${n} </td><td> ${allBooks[j].title} </td><td> ${allBooks[j].Price} </td></tr>`
            document.getElementById("tb").innerHTML += r;
            tP = tP + allBooks[j].Price;
            
            document.getElementById("t1").value = tP;
        }
        else{
            tP = tP;
        }
        
    }
   
}
return tP}
console.log(tP);
//how to take the tP variable out of the function;
// how to deduce??
//flexbox display
//console.log(fun3)

</script>

</html>
```

second trial
Html , css and Js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        img{
            margin: 3px;
            cursor: pointer;
            box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px 2px violet;
            border: 4px groove darkviolet;
        }
        div{
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
            grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr ;
            background-color: azure;
            padding: 7px;
            border: 4px groove greenyellow;
        }
        .c1{
            border: 10px ridge crimson;
        }
        #d2{
            display: flexbox;
            flex-basis: 4;
            background-color: bisque;
        }
        #b1{
            grid-column: 0/1;
            grid-row: 1/3;
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
            margin: 4px;
        }
        #t1{
            grid-column: 2/5;
            grid-row: 1/3;
            border: 3px solid blue;
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 1.5px 1px skyblue;
            margin:5px;
        }
        table{
            width: 100%;
            background-color: antiquewhite;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
            border: 4px solid sandybrown;
        }
        tr{
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr 1fr;
        }
        td{
            margin: 10px;
            color: turquoise;
            border: 1.5px solid black;
            padding: 6px;
            
        }
      
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="d1">
    <img src="b1.jpg" alt="book1" width="50%">
    <img src="b2.jpg" alt="book2" width="50%">
    <img src="b3.jpg" alt="book3" width="50%">
    <img src="b4.jpg" alt="book4" width="50%">
    <img src="b5.jpg" alt="book5" width="50%">
    <img src="b6.jpg" alt="book6" width="50%">
    <img src="b7.jpg" alt="book7" width="50%">
    <img src="b8.jpg" alt="book8" width="50%">
    </div>
    <table id="ta">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>SN:-</td>
                <td>Book name</td>
                <td>Price</td>
                
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tb">
            
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <input type="text" aria-label="price" id="t1">
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</body>
<script>
    var allBooks = [
        {name:"b1.jpg",title:"A Hero Born", Price: 20},
        {name:"b2.jpg",title:"Pearless Martial God", Price: 45},
        {name:"b3.jpg",title:"Five Rings Of Cultivation", Price: 14},
        {name:"b4.jpg",title:"Book Eater", Price: 19},
        {name:"b5.jpg",title:"Dual Sword God", Price: 15},
        {name:"b6.jpg",title:"Dragon Heart", Price: 18},
        {name:"b7.jpg",title:"Listening To Rain", Price: 55},
        {name:"b8.jpg",title:"The Hidden Blade", Price: 40}
    ];
    var selectedBooks = [];
    var b = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for(var i = 0 ; i < b.length;i++){
        b[i].addEventListener("click",fun);

    };
    var tP = 0;
    var sb = document.getElementsByClassName("c1");

    function fun(event){
        if(event.target.getAttribute("class")=="c1"){
        event.target.setAttribute("class","");
        document.getElementById("tb").innerHTML += r.remove();
        event.target.remove()
    }
        else{event.target.setAttribute("class","c1")}
        for(var i = 0; i < sb.length;i++){
        var ssb = sb[i].getAttribute("src");
        var n = 0;
        for(var j = 0 ; j < allBooks.length;j++ ){
            n ++;
            if(ssb==allBooks[j].name){
                var d = function (l){
                        l.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
            }
                var r = `<tr><td> ${n} </td><td> ${allBooks[j].title} </td><td> ${allBooks[j].Price} </td><td><button onclick="d(this)" class="fb">delete</button></td><tr>`
                    
            document.getElementById("tb").innerHTML += r;
            tP = tP + allBooks[j].Price;
            
            document.getElementById("t1").value = tP;
        }
        
    }
    };
  }  ;
//how to take the tP variable out of the function;
// how to deduce??
//flexbox display
</script>

</html>
```

Third trial
Html,css and Js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        img{
            margin: 3px;
            cursor: pointer;
            box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px 2px violet;
            border: 4px groove darkviolet;
        }
        div{
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
            grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr ;
            background-color: azure;
            padding: 7px;
            border: 4px groove greenyellow;
        }
        .c1{
            border: 10px ridge crimson;
        }
        #d2{
            display: flexbox;
            flex-basis: 4;
            background-color: bisque;
        }
        #b1{
            grid-column: 0/1;
            grid-row: 1/3;
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
            margin: 4px;
        }
        #t1{
            grid-column: 2/5;
            grid-row: 1/3;
            border: 3px solid blue;
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 1.5px 1px skyblue;
            margin:5px;
        }
        table{
            width: 100%;
            background-color: antiquewhite;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
            border: 4px solid sandybrown;
        }
        tr{
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr 1fr;
        }
        td{
            margin: 10px;
            color: turquoise;
            border: 1.5px solid black;
            padding: 6px;
            
        }
      
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="d1">
    <img src="b1.jpg" alt="book1" width="50%">
    <img src="b2.jpg" alt="book2" width="50%">
    <img src="b3.jpg" alt="book3" width="50%">
    <img src="b4.jpg" alt="book4" width="50%">
    <img src="b5.jpg" alt="book5" width="50%">
    <img src="b6.jpg" alt="book6" width="50%">
    <img src="b7.jpg" alt="book7" width="50%">
    <img src="b8.jpg" alt="book8" width="50%">
    </div>
    <table id="ta">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>SN:-</td>
                <td>Book name</td>
                <td>Price</td>
                
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tb">
            
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <input type="text" aria-label="price" id="t1">
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</body>
<script>
    var allBooks = [
        {name:"b1.jpg",title:"A Hero Born", Price: 20},
        {name:"b2.jpg",title:"Pearless Martial God", Price: 45},
        {name:"b3.jpg",title:"Five Rings Of Cultivation", Price: 14},
        {name:"b4.jpg",title:"Book Eater", Price: 19},
        {name:"b5.jpg",title:"Dual Sword God", Price: 15},
        {name:"b6.jpg",title:"Dragon Heart", Price: 18},
        {name:"b7.jpg",title:"Listening To Rain", Price: 55},
        {name:"b8.jpg",title:"The Hidden Blade", Price: 40}
    ];
    var selectedBooks = [];
    var b = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for(var i = 0 ; i < b.length;i++){
        b[i].addEventListener("click",fun);

    };
    var tP = 0;
    var sb = document.getElementsByClassName("c1");

    function fun(event){
        if(event.target.getAttribute("class")=="c1"){
        event.target.setAttribute("class","");
        document.getElementById("tb").innerHTML += r.remove();
        event.target.remove()
    }
        else{event.target.setAttribute("class","c1")}
        for(var i = 0; i < sb.length;i++){
        var ssb = sb[i].getAttribute("src");
        var n = 0;
        for(var j = 0 ; j < allBooks.length;j++ ){
            n ++;
            if(ssb==allBooks[j].name){
                var d = function (l){
                        l.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
            }
                var r = `<tr><td> ${n} </td><td> ${allBooks[j].title} </td><td> ${allBooks[j].Price} </td><td><button onclick="d(this)" class="fb">delete</button></td><tr>`
                    
            document.getElementById("tb").innerHTML += r;
            tP = tP + allBooks[j].Price;
            
            document.getElementById("t1").value = tP;
        }
        
    }
    };
  }  ;
//how to take the tP variable out of the function;
// how to deduce??
//flexbox display
</script>

</html>
```

Fourth trial
Html ,css and js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        img{
            margin: 3px;
            cursor: pointer;
            box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px 2px violet;
            border: 4px groove darkviolet;
        }
        div{
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
            grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr ;
            background-color: azure;
            padding: 7px;
            border: 4px groove greenyellow;
        }
        .c1{
            border: 10px ridge crimson;
        }
        #d2{
            display: flexbox;
            flex-basis: 4;
            background-color: bisque;
        }
        #b1{
            grid-column: 0/1;
            grid-row: 1/3;
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
            margin: 4px;
        }
        #t1{
            grid-column: 2/4;
            grid-row: 1/3;
            border: 3px solid blue;
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 1.5px 1px skyblue;
            margin:5px;
        }
        #b2{
            grid-column:4/5;
             grid-row: 1/3;
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
            margin: 4px;
        }
        table{
            background-color: antiquewhite;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
            border: 4px solid sandybrown;
        }
        tr{
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
        }
        td{
            margin: 10px;
            color: turquoise;
            border: 1.5px solid black;
            padding: 6px;
            
        }
      
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="d1">
    <img src="b1.jpg" alt="book1" width="50%">
    <img src="b2.jpg" alt="book2" width="50%">
    <img src="b3.jpg" alt="book3" width="50%">
    <img src="b4.jpg" alt="book4" width="50%">
    <img src="b5.jpg" alt="book5" width="50%">
    <img src="b6.jpg" alt="book6" width="50%">
    <img src="b7.jpg" alt="book7" width="50%">
    <img src="b8.jpg" alt="book8" width="50%">
    </div>
    <table id="ta">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>SN:-</td>
                <td>Book name</td>
                <td>Price</td>
                
                
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tb">
            
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <input type="button" value="price" id="b1" >  
            <input type="text" aria-label="price" id="t1">
            <input type="button" value="model" id="b2" >  
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</body>
<script>
    var allBooks = [
        {name:"b1.jpg",title:"A Hero Born", Price: 20},
        {name:"b2.jpg",title:"Pearless Martial God", Price: 45},
        {name:"b3.jpg",title:"Five Rings Of Cultivation", Price: 14},
        {name:"b4.jpg",title:"Book Eater", Price: 19},
        {name:"b5.jpg",title:"Dual Sword God", Price: 15},
        {name:"b6.jpg",title:"Dragon Heart", Price: 18},
        {name:"b7.jpg",title:"Listening To Rain", Price: 55},
        {name:"b8.jpg",title:"The Hidden Blade", Price: 40}
    ];
    var selectedBooks = [];
    var b = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for(var i = 0 ; i < b.length;i++){
        b[i].addEventListener("click",fun);

    };
    function fun(event){
        if(event.target.getAttribute("class")=="c1"){
        event.target.setAttribute("class","");}
        else{event.target.setAttribute("class","c1")}
        
    };
   ;
    var tP = 0;
    var sb = document.getElementsByClassName("c1");
    document.getElementById("b1").addEventListener("click",fun3);
    function fun3(){
    
    for(var i = 0; i < sb.length;i++){
        var ssb = sb[i].getAttribute("src");
        var n = 0;
        for(var j = 0 ; j < allBooks.length;j++ ){
            n ++;
            if(ssb==allBooks[j].name){
               
                var r = `<tr><td> ${n} </td><td> ${allBooks[j].title} </td><td> ${allBooks[j].Price} </td></tr>`
            document.getElementById("tb").innerHTML += r;
            tP = tP + allBooks[j].Price;
            
            document.getElementById("t1").value = tP;
        }
        else{
            tP = tP;
        }
        
    }
    console.log(tP);
}}
//how to take the tP variable out of the function;
// how to deduce??
//flexbox display
//console.log(fun3)
document.getElementById("b2").addEventListener("click",function(){
var ssa = document.getElementsByClassName("c1")
for(var i = 0 ; i<allBooks.length; i++){
    var sa = ssa[i].getAttribute("src");
    for(var j = 0;j<allBooks.length; j++)
    if(ssa == allBooks[j].name){
       var tt = 0 + allBooks[j].Price;
    }
}
    
    document.getElementById("t1").value = tt;
})
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement the functionality of removing selected books, you can modify the `fun` function to toggle the class and update the selected books array. Also, you can implement a function that removes books from the selection:

```html
// ...

<script>
    // ... your code

    function fun(event) {
        const bookImage = event.target;

        if (bookImage.classList.contains("c1")) {
            bookImage.classList.remove("c1");
            removeBookFromSelection(bookImage);
        } else {
            bookImage.classList.add("c1");
            addBookToSelection(bookImage);
        }
    }

    function addBookToSelection(bookImage) {
        const bookName = bookImage.getAttribute("src");
        const selectedBook = allBooks.find(book => book.name === bookName);
        if (selectedBook) {
            selectedBooks.push(selectedBook);
        }
    }

    function removeBookFromSelection(bookImage) {
        const bookName = bookImage.getAttribute("src");
        const indexToRemove = selectedBooks.findIndex(book => book.name === bookName);
        if (indexToRemove !== -1) {
            selectedBooks.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("b1").addEventListener("click", function () {
        tP = 0;
        selectedBooks.forEach(book => {
            tP += book.Price;
        });
        document.getElementById("t1").value = tP;
    });

    document.getElementById("b2").addEventListener("click", function () {
        tP = 0;
        selectedBooks = []; 
        document.getElementById("t1").value = tP;
    });
</script>
```

I added functions `addBookToSelection` and `removeBookFromSelection` to manage the selected books array.
 The `fun` function now updates this array accordingly, the "Price" button `b1` calculates the total price based on the selected books, and the "Model" button `b2` clears the selected books and resets the total price.